# Magento serialize grid input value save to custom module table

Tags: magento2, grid-serlization

I have created serialize product grid for my custom module. When I select products I got this value in post `1=cG9zaXRpb249&2=cG9zaXRpb249`.
How can I get only product ids from post value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Marius is right except `Mage::helper` is used in `Magento 1.x` versions

Here is the `Magento 2` equivalent:

You have to get the object of this class: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/6ea7d2d85cded3fa0fbcf4e7aa0dcd4edbf568a6/app/code/Magento/Backend/Helper/Js.php

**Method 1:**

```
    use \Magento\Backend\Helper\Js;

    protected $_backendJsHelper;

    public function __construct(
       .., 
       Js $backendJsHelper,
       ...
   ) {
          //other code..
          $this->_backendJsHelper = $backendJsHelper;
          //some other code..
    }

    public function execute() {
        //other code..
        $decodedOp = $this->_backendJsHelper->decodeGridSerializedInput($encodedData);
       //some other code..
    }
```

**Method 2:**
If you do not want to declare Backend Js Helper class in construct, you can also use another method which is as below:

```
$backendJsHelper = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Backend\Helper\Js');
$backendJsHelper->decodeGridSerializedInput($encodedData);
```

Method 1 is recommended as it is a better approach and as per the standard.

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Ahhhh. I missed the magento2 tag. Good answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Magento\Backend\Helper\Js` in your save controller action

```
$jsHelper = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Backend\Helper\Js');
$jsHelper->decodeGridSerializedInput('encode data');
```

You should get array